# How can we switch between different Implementations in Spring Context XML with an Boolean?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How can we switch between different Implementations in Spring Context XML with an Boolean?
    for example:

```
<bean id="detailsController"  class="com.something.detailsController" >
```

if true then

```
<property name="dao" ref="firstDao"/>
```

else

```
<property name="dao" ref="secoundDao"/>
```

I know in Spring3 we can work with profiles

Comment: Not sure if you can do this at xml level. What you can do probably is wire both daos as lazy init into the class and also wire the boolean condition. Then in the class use the dao as per the boolean condition. In that case the used dao's instance is only created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that by modifying your Java code and use Spring EL together with [`ApplicationAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html) and [`InitializingBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html).

```
public class DetailsController implements ApplicationContextAware, InitializingBean {

    private DetailsControllerDAO dao;

    private String daoName;

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        dao = applicationContext.getBean(daoName);
    }

    public void setDaoName(String daoName) {
        this.daoName = daoName;
    }

}
```

In XML:

```
<bean id="detailsController" class="com.something.detailsController">
    <property name="daoName" value="#{myCondition ? 'firstDao' : 'secondDao'}" />
</bean>
```

Of course, this solution has the disadvantage to add dependency to Spring code in your controller. To avoid that, you could move that code in a proxy class, as described by Guillaume Darmont.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this can be done at the XML level.

Answer (score 0):

Spring really cannot do that. See the bean lifecycle. Been classes are created, than properties are injected and than afterPropertiesSet() or @PostConstructor methods are invoked. Of course when I omit lazy initialized beans.

But if you want for testing etc. and so you need just the firstDao or the secondDao in your application at the sametime that depends just on your settings, you can use a bean factory. The bean factory creates your bean as you want. I also use it for to split development environment, test environment and production environment.

```
package com.dummyexample.config;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


/**
 *  Factory bean to create real or test dao.
 *  The result depends on realDaoEnabled configuration parameter.
 * 
 * @author Martin Strejc
 */
@Configuration
public class DaoBeanFactory {


    // mapping to servlet context configuration
    @Resource(mappedName = "realDaoEnabled")
    private Boolean realDaoEnabled = true;

    // TestDao extends or implements Dao
    @Autowired
    private TestDao testDao;

    // ProdDao extends or implements Dao
    @Autowired
    private ProdDao prodDao;

    public DaoBeanFactory() {
    }

    @Bean(name="dao")
    public Dao getDao() {
        if(realDaoEnabled) {
            return prodDao;
        }
        return testDao;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your DAOs are exchangeable, they inherits the same type (abstract class or interface). Thus you can write a `RoutingDetailsControllerDAO`.

Let's say that your common interface is named `DetailsControllerDAO`, with two methods `getDetails` and `getMoreDetails` inside, the code would be :

```
public class RoutingDetailsControllerDAO implements DetailsControllerDAO {
    private DetailsControllerDAO firstDAO;
    private DetailsControllerDAO secondDAO;

    protected DetailsControllerDAO getDAOToUse() {
       return YOUR_BOOLEAN_CONDITION ? firstDAO : secondDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public Details getDetails() {
       return getDAOToUse().getDetails();
    }

    @Override
    public Details getMoreDetails() {
       return getDAOToUse().getMoreDetails();
    }

    // Insert firstDAO and secondDAO setters below
    ...

}
```

Your Spring XML config is now :

```
<bean id="detailsController" class="com.something.detailsController" >
   <property name="dao" ref="routingDetailsControllerDAO"/>
</bean>
<bean id="routingDetailsControllerDAO" class="com.something.RoutingDetailsControllerDAO">
   <property name="firstDao" ref="firstDao"/>
   <property name="secondDao" ref="secondDao"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few possibilities:

- You can either use profiles (`<beans profiles="profileOne">`).
- You can use `FactoryBean` to create the correct DAO
- You can use SPeL

The last one is the easiest:

```
<bean id="detailsController" class="com.something.detailsController">
    <property name="dao" ref="#{condition ? 'firstDao' : 'secondDao'}" />
</bean>
```

Of course you can load bean name from properties file via property configurer:

```
<bean id="detailsController" class="com.something.detailsController">
    <property name="dao" ref="${bean.name.from.properties.file}" />
</bean>
```